# Setting and keeping resolution settings for a display that's not autodetected on KDE/Fedora 20

Tags: kde, fedora-20

I have a non standard 1280x800 screen which isn't detected correctly by my linux system

The screen is a 1280x800 native, [10.1 inch tablet display with an external controller board](http://www.dx.com/p/10-1-digital-ips-screen-1280-x-800-drive-board-for-raspberry-pcduino-cubieboard-black-275804). I've got it connected to a [brix](http://www.gigabyte.sg/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5038#ov) with a [N2807 Celeron](http://ark.intel.com/products/81072/Intel-Celeron-Processor-N2807-1M-Cache-up-to-2_16-GHz) via HDMI. I run Fedora 20 KDE spin with [official intel i915 drivers](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/).

The screen resolution is *not* detected and it defaults to a *horrible* 1024x786, and the closest supported resolution is 1200 x768 and I have a script that adds the correct resolution, enables it for the device and sets it (so, xrandr newmode, then addmode, then output - but you knew that).

While this is a single user system, I'd like to either add this set this resolution *before* login (which would be utterly ace) or to have this script preloaded before *any* user logs in.

Failing which where would I *put* this script for KDE?

Comment: _1280x800, non standard_ ah those good old days of 16:10 laptop displays

Comment: Its probably the controller not the display that's non standard. I'm convinced its a tablet panel, and it has a few odd features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ended up finding the answer myself - credit [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56466/27961) since that let me automate the process somewhat.

I created a script as mentioned previously that handled creating a new screen mode. I saved this as xrandr.sh and made sure it was executable. I used gtf to generate the modeline (`gtf 1280 800 60.0` - horizontal resolution, vertical resolution and frequency - most folk seem to do it to one decimal point so I did so) and used that to generate the script and a bare xrandr command to work out the output name.

That spits out something like

```
[geek@phoebe ~]$ gtf 1280 800 60

  # 1280x800 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 49.68 kHz; pclk: 83.46 MHz
  Modeline "1280x800_60.00"   83.50  1280 1352 1480 1680  800 803 809 831   -HSync +Vsync
```

The stuff after modeline is what's interesting - you use that to set the mode.

I saved this as xrandr.sh

```
xrandr --newmode  "1280x800_60.00"   83.50  1280 1352 1480 1680  800 803 809 831 -hsync +vsync 
xrandr --addmode HDMI1 "1280x800_60.00"
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1280x800_60.00
```

This *generates* a new mode you can use anywhere, then tells your system to allow you to use that mode for the output HDMI1, and tells you to *change* the resolution settings to that mode.

I then set it to get started by 'autostart'. *Logically* I should be able to start this pre-kde, but run on startup works (I suspect the screen res is being changed post login- it looks sharp *until* I log on - I guess that's another problem though).

[image]

This runs the script after I login, and the screen is entirely usable at the proper resolution for the rest of the session. It's not *perfect* (It would probably need to be disabled for another screen, for example) but it works well enough for now.