# Trouble connecting Dell E6420 to 27" Korean Monitor

Tags: ubuntu, display, hdmi, connection

First time posting so please forgive my ignorance on this hardware issue.

TL;DR I can't figure out if the issue is due to graphics card incompatibility or because of choice of connecting cables.

I have recently received a beautiful 27" Crossover 27Q display from Korea and was having some issues connecting it to my laptop as a secondary display.

I am currently using a Dell Latitude E6420 and am running Ubuntu 14.04. My processor is a Intel® Core™ i7-2640M CPU @ 2.80GHz and the graphics is  Intel® Sandybridge Mobile.

My first guess is that my laptop, and in particular the graphics, is simply too underpowered to run this particular monitor and it is time for an upgrade.

I am attempting to connect with a DVI-D to HDMI cable and the display is not turning on. When I go to system settings and attempt to turn on the secondary display through the Display Menu I get an error message.

I have the following ports for connecting; USB/VGA/HDMI/eSATA.

My second guess is that I am using the wrong cable and need to connect via  a DVI-D to eSATA adapter.

What's the answer guys?

Regards,

A

[image: error_message 1]

[image: error_message 2]

Comment: What error message ? Pictures would be nice

Comment: Good point. I've just updated the post with two pictures of the two errors that I get when I try to turn on the 2nd monitor.

Comment: Korean monitors are notoriously picky over outputs. IIRC anything but DVI-D DL connectors may be problematic. Are your converters active or passive?

Comment: It came with a DVI-D DL but I am not using it. Instead I bought a DVI-D to HDMI cable http://www.ncix.com/detail/ngear-hdmi-to-dvi-d-dual-03-98350.htm this one exactly and I am not using any converter. I think this means that they are considered "passive".

Comment: That might possibly be the issue. What happens when you manually create the modline and set it with xrandr like I did here? http://superuser.com/a/809799/10165

Comment: Thanks for answering JG! I'm just concerned about breaking the monitor by forcing to run at a certain resolution, I dunno if this correct thinking but it's outside my scope of knowledge. I think the main problem is that my graphics card doesn't support it period. I found this ad that specifies that laptop and onboard graphics cards are not supported. Heres the link, scroll about halfway: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Crossover-27q-led-p-27-Dvi-Monitor-De-Computadora-Qhd-2560x1440-16-9-pivote-/320865620246?_ul=AR  My fault for not doing my due diligence before I bought this. Thank you for trying!