# How to run a Bash script when using a graphical desktop login

Tags: linux, boot, bash, arch-linux, mate

I am running the MATE desktop on Arch Linux, and I have a bash script that I run which:

- Configures MATE to work with multiple monitors
- Connects the PC to the internet
- Changes my mouse speed

I have to manually execute this script every time I login graphically. How can I do this automatically? I have tried the following:

- Putting the script in a `~/.profile` file. Nothing happened.
- Putting the script in a `~/.initrc` file. Nothing happened.
- Putting the script in a `~/.xsession` file. Nothing happened.
- systemd won't work because, as far as I can tell, it tries to execute the script functions too early. It must be executed only once the user has logged in, not during startup.

**Edit**: The script require root privledges aswell!

Comment: I don't run mate - but something similar to KDE's autostart module might be handy. http://superuser.com/a/809799/10165 is an example of me doing a xrandr script with autostart. Mate might call it startup applications. I *don't* have a mate desktop to test it on and to post a full answer, so if anyone does, and wants to post an answer with this I'm cool.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Funny enough my script also does the same `xrandr` commands that you laid out in your question.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek After using the MATE autostart application I am sorry to report that I must manually put in the root password when I startup.

Comment: you can give sudo permissions for a single command too. That might be a better idea. And since it works, post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a comment by @JorneymanGeek I have been able to use the MATE autostart application to do what I need. I resolved to issues that come with needing to put in a password by using NOPASSWD in `visudo`, which allows me to call `sudo COMMAND` at the command line wihtout using a password.

This is generally a bad idea, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can sometimes (not always) use `~/.xsession` to achieve what you want. This is usually very system dependent and you may have to dig through your system's startup script. Please see [this Unix & Linux Stack Exchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47359/what-is-xsession-for) for more details

Comment: Unfortunately ~/.session doesn't work in my case.

Comment: @SpenserTruex Yeah, it doesn't work always. Just to confirm, the filename is  `~/.xsession` NOT `~/.session`.

Comment: it is `~/.xsession`.

Comment: @SpenserTruex OK. I'm not an Arch user. After some more digging around `~/.xprofile` seems to be the [session start file](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xprofile) used by most modern display managers.

Answer (score 0):

You could either put it in:

- `~/.bashrc` (will run after all apps initialized)
- `/etc/rc.local` (will run AS ROOT after all services are running, but before you logon with your username)

Comment: Is there a way to run `~/.bashrc` as root to get both the benefits or running after apps have initialized *and* as root?

Comment: Also I tried using rc.local and it produces no results.