# How to set the kernel modesetting console modeline and vga polarity?

Tags: linux, vga, monitor-settings, modeline

This question is an extension of [this one](https://superuser.com/q/1150860).
My problem is my Aspeed video card (not a gpu) ends up dectecting and using the [wrong video polarity](https://superuser.com/q/1150860) that results in an a off bound video output along a resolution the screen doesn’t recognizes.
This happens both in Xorg and the kernel virtual console and with generic video drivers as well as the official deprecated Linux Aspeed drivers. [image]
It should be noted that I didn’t had this problem with that screen the last time I used vga output with an old agp Nvidia card 15 years ago.
Neverless, the more recent Windows based official driver doesn’t have this problem. [image].

Based on the documentation,
[image] how do I set the correct polarity or get the right video polarity to be detected correctly?

Comment: What is the native resolution of the display? Have you tried just specifying some or other standard resolution via `video=`, without any extra tweaks? (Your photo shows KDE using 1680x1050, is that correct?) Also, have you tried a different VGA cable, just in case? (I've had a few cases where old VGA cables prevented the graphics adapter from receiving EDID data from the display, and therefore from detecting the correct video mode.)

Comment: @user1686 16880 by 1050 is the native resolution as correctly detected by Linux. Otherwise, yes I tried this. **As you can see with the Windows picture were it works this has no link to the hardware. This is a software driver problem**. The monitor states the difference is the electrical polarity which is reversed on Windows were it works. Also edid contains no informations about polarity.